# Issue with ajax file upload (Node.js, express, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, file-upload

I am struggling to get a file upload script working. I am using a node/express backend with jQuery firing off the ajax request.

Markup:

```
<input id="audio" type="file" name="audio">
```

Front end JS:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("audio", e.data.audio, 'testname');

$.ajax({
    url: 'api/upload',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

using a custom written module that executes the following and places it into e.data.audio

```
if(has('fileReader')){
    return this.$input[0].files[0] || '';
}
```

When i select as small audio file to upload and submit, e.data.audio has the following value at the point it is set into the ajax function argument object:

Lack of SO streetcred means I need to put images on imgur
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAjfb.png

After the request is sent I am using the files property of the request object (req.files) to get access to the file, in order to save it.

```
exports.upload = function(){
    return function(req, res){
        console.log(req.files);
        if (req.files && req.files.audio){
            var file = req.files.audio;
            fs.readFile(file.path, function(err, data){
                if (err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                var newPath = __dirname + 'public/audio';
                fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err){
                    if (err){
                        res.send(err);
                    }else{
                        res.send(true);
                    }
                });

            })
        }else{

        }
    }
};
```

However the issue is that the path always seems to be the clients local path.

Lack of SO streetcred means I need to put images on imgur
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMvZn.png

Ive done a fair amount of googling and cant seem to find anything along the same lines. I am obviously just missing something basic and need someone to point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

`file.path` is the path to the temporary file that was created on the server that holds the uploaded file data, it's not the path of the file from the uploader's system.

On an unrelated note, `__dirname` does not include a trailing slash so you'll probably want this:

```
var newPath = __dirname + '/public/audio';
```

instead of:

```
var newPath = __dirname + 'public/audio';
```

Also you probably should use [`fs.rename`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) to move the file instead of reading the whole file into memory and then writing it back out again. Example:

```
var file = req.files.audio;

fs.rename(file.path, __dirname + '/public/audio', function(err) {
  res.send(err ? err : true);
});
```

Comment: The issue was with the path not having a trailing slash rather than anything to do with the temp file on the server. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: `req.files` is always `undefined`, any suggestion on that?